# SQL ALL vs EXISTS Performance

Tags: sql, t-sql, sqlperformance

How do these two WHERE clauses compare in performance? `isFoo` is a bit/boolean field.

```
WHERE 1 = ALL (SELECT isFoo FROM barTable)
```

versus

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT isFoo FROM barTable WHERE isFoo = 0)
```

I've been looking around and it's been hard to find any documentation or tests on `ALL`'s performance. Does it short-circuit out? Is there a noteworthy performance difference between these two?

EDIT:

Both of the execution plans are identical in every way. Could it be possible that both queries are being optimized to the same execution plan?

Comment: Have you compared the execution plans? Any measurements?

Comment: The execution plans turn out to be suspiciously identical (as far as the Subtree Cost). Not sure if the difference is just that negligible, or if I'm misinterpreting them.

Comment: Modern SQL engines are remarkably good at identifying like-result queries and executing them the same way. The only way to answer your question for specific queries is to test them.

Comment: The two are not identical, unless `isFoo` only takes on the values of 0 and 1.  I wouldn't expect the execution plans to be identical in all details.

Comment: To revise my first comment; Both of the execution plans are identical in every way. Could it be possible that both queries are being optimized to the same execution plan?